# Docker Update old pem file

Tags: docker, ssl, azure-devops

So far I have generated my own pem file and moved it to my ubuntu virtual machine on azure resources group which has one of our backend api.

after running `docker secret ls` I have got to know there is one .pem key which was created an year ago and has to be updated with the new one that I have in my `/home/cert/cert.pem` directory.

I have read the docker documentation and it says I have to start with `docker secret create` but my concern is I have already my own .pem and just need to update it with old one.

How can do I it and is it safe to do that? my concern is to update old SSL expired certificate with new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out `docker secret create new_name.pem /file/path/name` 
it will create the new.pem and can be verified by `docker secret ls`
then need to verify the service as I was using haproxy so it can be done:

`docker service update --secret-add new_name.pem haproxy`
and remove the old 
`docker service update --secret-rm old_name haproxy`
verify it with `docker service inspect haproxy` if you find the new one you are done!

finally restart VM on azure portal!